# google apps script error: Index (row 7, column 0) is out of bounds

Tags: google-apps-script

Noob project in GAS, When I publish to web app and look it generates the error above.  "Index (row 7, column 0) is out of bounds" i have never seen that and I looked and others have encountered the problem mostly while doing complicated array functions. But this little guy is fairly simple I think anyway. Stumped!
    Any help you can give me to point me in the right direction would be awesome.

```
var submissionSSKey = '1Ccj_g3HtkHOcdAtn_9LHUxUrbsh5ZJYVUs3hWC9-Cuo';
var docurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ccj_g3HtkHOcdAtn_9LHUxUrbsh5ZJYVUs3hWC9-Cuo/edit'
var LOCATION = ['Select a Location','A Res','B Res','C Res','D Res','MNT','OSB','TWB','VP','VM','SITE DEV']
var QCREP = ['Select a REP','David','Ryan','Herschell','Bill','Nick ','Stephe','Beth ']
var Shop = ['Select a SHOP','Walls/Ceilings','Plumbing','Electrical','HVAC/Sheet Metal','Carpentry','Interiors','Exteriors','Masonry','Mechanics','Structural']
var ISSUETYPE = ['Select an ISSUE TYPE','Poor Workmanship','Lack of Training','Not Per Plans','Not Per Code','Not Per Spec','Plan Conflict']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'solid','borderWidth':'10PX','borderColor':'#bbbbbb'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QC Observation').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 600);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>QC Observation</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(7,2).setId('grid');
  var location = app.createListBox().setName('location').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in LOCATION){location.addItem(LOCATION[i])}    
  var QCREP = app.createListBox().setName('QCREP').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in QCREP){QCREP.addItem(QCREP[i])}  
  var Shop = app.createListBox().setName('Shop').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in Shop){Shop.addItem(Shop[i])}  
  var ISSUETYPE = app.createListBox().setName('ISSUETYPE').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in ISSUETYPE){ISSUETYPE.addItem(ISSUETYPE[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('200px').setName('TB1');
  var OBDate = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('OBdate');
  var FOLLOWDate = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('FOLLOwDate');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var upLoad1 = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile1');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(location,'Select a LOCATION').validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload');


  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(upLoad1, 'FileUpload').forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontsize','12px');

  var cliHandler4 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 250).validateNotMatches(location,'Select a LOCATION').validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'LOCATION')
      .setWidget(1, 1, location.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'QC REP')
      .setWidget(2, 1, QCREP.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'SHOP RESPONSIBLE')
      .setWidget(3, 1, Shop.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(4, 0, 'ISSUE TYPE')
      .setWidget(4, 1, ISSUETYPE.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(5, 0, 'OBSERVATION')
      .setWidget(5, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler4))
      .setText(6, 0, 'OBSERVATION DATE')
      .setWidget(6, 1, OBDate.addValueChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(7, 0, 'FOLLOW UP DATE')
      .setWidget(7, 1, FOLLOWDate.addValueChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(8, 0, 'IMAGE FILE')
      .setWidget(8, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(9, 1, upLoad1.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3))
      .setWidget(11, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(11, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','orange');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log('Value of e is: ' + e);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.location;
  var ListVal = e.parameter.QCREP;
  var ListVal = e.parameter.Shop;
  var ListVal = e.parameter.ISSUETYPE;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var dateVal = e.parameter.OBDate;
  var dateVal2 = e.parameter.FOLLOWDate;
  var fileBlob1 = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob1 = fileBlob1.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img1 = DocsList.createFile(blob1);
  var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.uploadedFile1;
  var blob2 = fileBlob2.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img2 = DocsList.createFile(blob2);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img1.addToFolder(folder);
  img1.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  img2.addToFolder(folder);
  img2.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight1 = parseInt(img1.getSize()/1000);
  var weight2 = parseInt(img2.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[ListVal,textVal,dateVal,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img1.getId(),"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img2.getId()]]);
  var image1Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 6).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img1.getId()+'")');
  var image2Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 7).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img2.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['LOCATION : '+ListVal,'QCREP : '+ListVal,'SHOP : '+ListVal,'ISSUE TYPE : '+ListVal,'OBSERVATION : '+textVal,'OBDate : '+dateVal,'FOLLOWDate : '+dateVal2]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img1);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight1+' kB)   ');
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img2);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight2+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

```
var grid = app.createGrid(7,2).setId('grid');
```

The rows in the grid are zero indexed.  Row one is index zero.  Row seven is index 6.  You are creating seven rows, which means that you can only refer to a row by index up to the number 6.

[UI Grid Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/grid)

When this line of code, on line 55 is run:

```
.setText(7, 0, 'FOLLOW UP DATE')
```

It's referring to the eighth row, which doesn't exist.  You can't set a text item into a row that doesn't exist, it's "out of bounds".

You need to change the grid to this, with 12 rows:

```
var grid = app.createGrid(12,2).setId('grid');
```

The Ui Service is Deprecated.  You're putting lots of work into something that will probably not be supported in the future.

Comment: yes i Know is deprecated but nobody has clued me in how to do the same thing in the new version , hint hint all

Comment: If I provided the right answer, please show your appreciation by marking it as the correct answer, and up-voting.  Feel free to visit my profile page, and send me an email.

Comment: hanks sandy, i will mark it as correct once i qualify :) right now i need a few more rep points to vote -            in the mean time if you have a minute i am still working on this here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254058/gas-listbox-breaks-dopost