# GAS Listbox breaks doPost

Tags: google-apps-script, listbox

Code works ok and posts (except cell 3 says "not found" where i deleted the email field, any help here is also welcome) until i add the second listbox (listitems2) somehow it breaks the code and it wont post.

The execution transcript shows no issues on doGet so I assume the problem is in doPost. Any help is much appreciated

```
var submissionSSKey = '...LE0tU';
var docurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...LE0tU/edit'
var listitems = ['Select a Location','A Res','B Res','C Res','D Res','MNT','OSB','TWB','VP','VM','SITE DEV']
var listitems2 = ['Select a REP','David','Ryan','Beth']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'#dddddd','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'solid','borderWidth':'10PX','borderColor':'#bbbbbb'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QC Observation').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 300);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>QC Observation</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','25PX');
  var grid = app.createGrid(12,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])} 
  var list2 = app.createListBox().setName('list2').setWidth('130');
   for(var i in listitems2){list2.addItem(listitems2[i])} 
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var upLoad1 = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile1');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','18px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a Location').validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload');


  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(upLoad1, 'FileUpload').forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontsize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'LOCATION')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'QC CONTACT')
      .setWidget(2, 1, list2.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(7, 0, 'OBSERVATION')
      .setWidget(7, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(8, 0, 'Image File')
      .setWidget(8, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(9, 1, upLoad1.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3))
      .setWidget(11, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(11, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal = e.parameter.list1;
  var ListVal2 = e.parameter.list2;
  var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
  var fileBlob1 = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var blob1 = fileBlob1.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img1 = DocsList.createFile(blob1);
  var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.uploadedFile1;
  var blob2 = fileBlob2.setContentTypeFromExtension()
  var img2 = DocsList.createFile(blob2);
  try{
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
  }catch(e){DocsList.createFolder('photos');var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')}
  img1.addToFolder(folder);
  img1.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  img2.addToFolder(folder);
  img2.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var weight1 = parseInt(img1.getSize()/1000);
  var weight2 = parseInt(img2.getSize()/1000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[ListVal,ListVal2,textVal,,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img1.getId(),"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img2.getId()]]);
  var image1Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 6).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img1.getId()+'")');
  var image2Insert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 7).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+img2.getId()+'")');
  sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow+1, 80);
  var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
  GDoc.appendTable([['Location : '+ListVal,'QCRep : '+ListVal2,'Note : '+textVal,]])
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img1);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight1+' kB)   ');
  var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img2);
  var width = inlineI.getWidth();
  var newW = width;
  var height = inlineI.getHeight();
  var newH = height;
  var ratio = width/height;
  Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
  if(width>640){
  newW = 640;
  newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
  }
  inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
  GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : '+width+' x '+height+' (eventually) resized to '+newW+' x '+newH+' for PREVIEW ('+weight2+' kB)   ');
  GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
  GDoc.saveAndClose();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```